# Is there a better way to work with interfaces and get rid of 'TypeErrors'?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typeerror, react-props

I'm stucked in a `TypeError` in my ReactJS project.
The error:

```
Server Error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'phoneNumber')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Source:
~/components/index.tsx (74:28)
> 74 | phoneNumber: props.data.manager.phoneNumber,
```

The code below is where the compiler claims to have a `TypeError`.

```
const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(formSchema),
    defaultValues: defaultValues,
});

interface DataProps {
  id: number;
  accountTypeEnum: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}
//The function below is inside the main function. I didn't paste the entire code so this question doesn't get too much big
const defaultValues: DataProps = {
    id: props.data.id,
    accountTypeEnum: props.data.accountTypeEnum,
    phoneNumber: props.data.manager.phoneNumber, //here's where the error occurs
  }
```

So after that i have a form that will be used to change the user's info. Basically the form starts with the `defaultValues` and so the user can change if he want it.

```
return(
 <Form>
  <Input
     name="phone"
     type={"text"}
     label="Phone Number"
     error={errors.phoneNumber}
     mask="phone"
     {...register("phone")}
   />
 </Form>
);
```

When i delete the 74º line the page renders but the info doesn't show. I know that this is happening cause `phoneNumber` is undefined but i really don't know how to fix that. I'm a newbie into Typescript as you may see.
You can [click here to see the entire typescript file on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/CN2vK7y6).

Comment: Can you try printing out `props.data`? It's not the function's fault. It's whoever's passing the data's fault.

Comment: `console.log(props.data)` returns an `object` with all the data i want to show. But for some reason this data doesn't appears on the forms. Do you think there is a problem in the way i wrote the `Form`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So whenever you see error like this, that normally means anything to the left of the dot right before the `phoneNumber` is undefined. In this case, it could be your `props.data.manager` is undefined. Double check if you forgot to pass it down as a prop.

Comment: Well, if i do `console.log(props.data)` it returns the object with all the info i need, but if i do `console.log(props.data.manager)` i get `undefined`.

Comment: Either `manager` field not included in `data` object, or `manager` field is with value `undefined`, in this case if you do see `manager` in your `data` object, then it is `{manager: undefined}`. You will need to assign it a value if you want to get `phoneNumber` from it, then it should look like something as `{manager: {phoneNumber: 12345}}`